# filter gcp web api get disk list according prefix

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm working with Google Cloud Web API.
I'm trying to find all the disks with a name start with "diskname".

I'm filtering the disks list using the filter property and regex expression.
I'm using the following regex:

```
diskname.*
```

My full URL is:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/zones/myzone/disks?filter=name%3D~diskname.*
```

But I'm keep getting http 400 Bad Request with message:

> "Invalid value for field 'filter': 'name=~diskname.*'. Invalid list
>   filter expression."

I also try all the options from the following [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference)

But still the same error

Comment: Where in the API documentation do you see support for regex?

Comment: In gcloud there is a support for filter and regex. Not sure if it's the same in the Web API. 
It would be very strange if google didn't support that. I search for couple of hours but didn't find the documentation of google that indicate that they support more than == != ...

Comment: It would be strange if a low-level API supported regex. You need to implement that functionality in your program. Languages like Python make regex simple.

Comment: No it is not, there is no sense to get all disk from zone (like in my example) a query that potentially can results thousands of results instead only a three or four according filter on the name.

Comment: We can help you with programming questions and problems. We cannot help you with the politics of how companies design their systems. However, your opinion is not backed by how AWS, Azure, Alibaba and Google design their systems. You will need to adjust your software to fit their designs. What you think is common sense may not be the case when you consider the impact of millions of API calls per second.